# Javascript Facebook API Post

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I just want make a script who post when i make the login. I find this code

```
var body = 'i13 App - Post test';
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
         }else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
```

it work with Facebook javascipt Test Console, but when i put in my script i never can post and received the alert('error occured),

Thz for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the page code correctly? ensure you have the following code within the page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

After the user is logged in successfully you can have a button trigger the following code"

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/